# Do electric cars corrode faster?

Tags: rust, peugeot, body, electric-vehicle

I am buying a new Peugeot e-208 (Full electric) and I noticed something strange in the contract:

Peugeot warrants all its new cars for 12 years against corrosion, but for electric cars they reduce the warranty to 7 years.

This is somewhat strange as the e-208 is supposed to be exactly the same platform and body as the thermal version.

There is a reason for every line in a contract, so what could it be?
Does an electric car corrode faster?  Maybe there is some interaction with the charging system that enhances oxidation.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty wild. I wouldn't think so, however, maybe they cannot use the undercoating on the electric car they do on the non? Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing inherent in an electric vehicle that makes it corrode faster.  I suspect they are simply using the fact that it's electric as an excuse to reduce their liability to cover corrosion.

Comment: Indeed, it might be simply a red herring for reducing the warranty coverage. However they generally take great pride of the extent of theirs garanties, so I tend to think that they changed it for a reason.

Comment: I believe that the 12 year warranty is given not because the car is so well designed and built that it will last that long, but that competitive pressures have forced it.  I'm not familiar with Peugeot quality (they are not imported into the USA so they are pretty rare) but I have found that the length of warranty is not a reliable indicator of the quality.  In many cases the manufacturer is betting on the fact that most people will not keep their car that long or that something else will fail before the corrosion kicks in.

Comment: True. The battery has a warranty of 8 years, so there is some correlation with the length of the anti-corrosion warranty.

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE I suspect this is to prevent warranty claims on potential corrosion under / behind the battery when the battery has to be changed (out of warranty) after those 8 years.